# Embedding matplotlib in tkinter - examples freeze

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to embed a matplotlib figure in a tkinter application, so the first place to start is an [example from matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html), right?

I'm using Anaconda 4.0.5 with python 3.5.1. When I try and run the example code, the application freezes. As in, if I run it with python.exe, the console freezes and I have to force close it. No tkinter window shows up.

In this code:

```
f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t, s)


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
```

The issue seems to be with the last line, canvas.show(). If I comment this out, the window at least shows up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with Python 3, despite what the tutorials I've followed said. If I run it using Python 2.7, it runs without an issue. Any version of Python 3, however, causes it to crash

EDIT: I tracked the error to anaconda - apparently the matplotlib tk and tkinter versions are different, which causes the error. Running with python 2.7 still works fine.